# Lock windows computer while logging in?

Tags: windows, networking, authentication

My company's network log-in process takes ages (at least to my impatient mind).

I would like to log into the network, but immediately lock the computer while the long log-in process rumbles along so I can safely go and make a cup of tea, then come back and unlock the computer and be fully logged in, but with a cup of tea.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win+L is the shortcut to lock Windows, but that might actually be to early to be working at that moment - depending whether your login-process is tightly integrated or run "after login".

Comment: It's a Citrix login - and it works ... never thought of using Win+L before login.